# Actualizar base de datos al cerrar página web

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, jsp

Tengo una tabla `usuarios` en la base de datos y tiene un atributo `estado` que puede ser `ACTIVO` o `INACTIVO`, entonces cuando inicia sesión le cambio el estado a `ACTIVO`. Quiero que cuando se cierre el navegador cambie el estado a `INACTIVO`.

Son repartidores y tienen 3 estados, `ACTIVO`, `REPARTIENDO` Y `INACTIVO`, entonces cuando le asigno pedidos y sale a repartir, le cambio a `REPARTIENDO` , cuando se inicia sesión en la app `ACTIVO` y cuando se cierra sesión `INACTIVO`.

La sesión puede estar abierta una sola vez, entonces al hacer login controlo que el repartidor no tenga el estado `ACTIVO`.

Entonces yo quiero que al cerrar el navegador le cambio el estado por si cierra la ventana y no cerro sesión.

¿Hay alguna forma de poder hacerlo?
Estoy en un proyecto Java Web Application, podría ser con Javascript, JSP Servlet, cualquier forma.

Comment: Es una mala practica hacer esto, no hay garantía de que el browser pueda enviar el mensaje, la respuesta aceptada es horrible. Podría, por ejemplo, quedarse sin conexión a internet y se rompe todo el sistema que depende de este estado. No tiene sentido y en el caso de que lo necesites realmente, lo deberías manejar del lado del servidor. Igualmente no hay forma confiable de hace este seguimiento, por lo tanto no tiene sentido hacerlo, deberías plantear el problema de fondo para que podamos darte una solución real.

Comment: Ahí actualice la pregunta.

Comment: Una duda, por que la limitación de que `La sesión puede estar abierta una sola vez` ? ¿cual es el problema de que el repartidor tenga abierta la aplicación en 2 browsers/lugares a la vez?

Comment: Es un requerimiento del cliente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías suscribir una función al evento [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) para marcarlo como inactivo. El evento se disparará ya sea porque cerro la pagina o se movió a otra.

Si el caso fuera que se movio a otra página, podrías re-activarlo suscribiendo otra función al evento [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load)

Ejemplo:

```js
function actualizarEstado(estado) {
  console.log(estado);
}
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
  actualizarEstado('activo');
});
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {
  actualizarEstado('inactivo');
});
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com">Ir a Google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

no entiendo cual sería el fin de hacer eso, entendería el fin si quisieras hacer algún tipo chat en tiempo real, de lo contrario yo pienso que la columna esta de más, si quisieras controlar el tiempo de sesión podrías poner que después de cierto tiempo de inactividad te saque de la página en automático. Por lo regular así se maneja en la mayoria de los sitios ya que tu puedes cerrar el navegador, abrirlo y continuar con la sesión hasta que ese tiempo se cumpla. Otra cosa que puedes hacer es cachar con javascript cuando se cierre el navegador con el evento "onbeforeunload" hacer una llamada ajax al servidor y cambiar el estado.

Saludos.